# update tree structure in django models

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, tree

I have this tree of nodes, which I should store them in sqlite database. I'm using this tree like a cache so I have to be able to read fast, but also I'm going to update it periodically. I have seen `django-treebeard` which has some easy to use functions, but I'm still not sure about the update part. Is there any better library for this case? or what is the best implementation of update which I can add to `django-treebeard` functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

I use `django-mptt` in my projects when I have some sort of Tree architecture.

> MPTT is a technique for storing hierarchical data in a database. The
> aim is to make retrieval operations very efficient.
>
> The trade-off for this efficiency is that performing inserts and
> moving items around the tree is more involved, as there's some extra
> work required to keep the tree structure in a good state at all times.

--- From [the README](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)